# http://localhost:3000/bookmarks が表示されません。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby on railsの勉強中ですが、TODOLISTのアプリ作成のため、「http://localhost:3000/bookmarks」を利用しております。
しかし、とある作業中に上記URLにアクセスしても表示されなくなってしまいました。
この対策をご教示頂けませんでしょうか？

現在、「rails server」のコマンドは打っており、サーバーは起動しております。

Comment: サーバー側のログを提示できませんか? そうすることで有益な回答が得られやすくなります。

Comment: 「表示されなくなった」をもう少し具体的に書いていただけると良いと思います。例えば「エラーが表示される」や「ずっとまたされた後に"ページが見つかりません"と出る」、「画面上に変化が見られない」等など。

Comment: 現状のターミナル画像になります。
https://gyazo.com/7e97db2b74f3a267e0613f5dac5bf3ea

Comment: 表示されないというのは↓のような状態です。 
https://gyazo.com/2524713fc97ec8383a3de6c13f9e3145 

右下に「localhostを待機しています・・・」という文字が表示されるも、 その状態がずっと続き変わりません。

Answer (score 1):

ターミナル画面の様子を見ると、app/controllers/bookmarks_controller.rbのindexアクションの中での中で`binding.pry`が書かれている行でサーバーの動作が止まっており、サーバーからのレスポンスが返ってきていないため真っ白で表示されない状態になっているのだと思います。

ターミナルで`continue`や⌘+Dを入力しbinding.pryで停止した行から抜けたり、`binding.pry`が書かれた行をコメントアウトして再度rails sしてアクセスしなおすと表示されると思います。

参考: http://qiita.com/k0kubun/items/b118e9ccaef8707c4d9f#pry-byebug

[image: ターミナル画面]